# Add a column to dataframe in R based on grater/less than condition based on the values in existing columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe and want to create a new column Z populated with a value of "tw" or "ok" for each record. If x > y, z = "ok" , IF x < y, z = "tw".

```
  x y 
a 1 2
b 2 3
c 5 1
```

result

```
  x y z
a 1 2 tw
b 2 3 tw
c 5 1 ok
```

Comment: if this is a data frame - what is the first column with 'a, b, c'? Can you `dput` your reproducible data source please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try `ifelse()` like below

```
df <- within(df,z <- ifelse(x>y,"ok","tw"))
```

If you do not define the output for the case "x==y", maybe you should add the following line

```
df$z[df$x==df$y] <- NA
```

Comment: In this case if x=y, z will be "tw".I think, this is not exactly the same with what is asked

Answer (score 4):

alternatively you can do it on the dataframe directly:

```
# creation of dataframe
df = data.frame("x" = c(1, 2, 5), "y" = c(2, 3, 1))

# column creation of z
df$z[(df$x > df$y)] <- "ok"
df$z[(df$x < df$y)] <- "tw"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this directly :

```
df$z <- c("tw", "ok")[(df$x > df$y) + 1]
df
#  x y  z
#a 1 2 tw
#b 2 3 tw
#c 5 1 ok
```

Not exactly clear what you want to do when `x == y` (above assigns "ok").

---

We can also use `case_when` from `dplyr` to assign values based on various condition.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(z = case_when(x > y ~"ok", 
                       x < y ~"tw", 
                       TRUE ~ NA_character_))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(1L, 2L, 5L), y = c(2L, 3L, 1L), z = c("tw", 
"tw", "ok")), row.names = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "data.frame")
```